# SG resources list in Veritas SFHA

Tags: cluster-computing

How can I extract (from `main.cf` or by a command) the resources list divided by Service group.

For example, I have a multi SG cluster and I need to print for each SG: DG, Vol and mountpoints. How can I do it without having to parse the `main.cf` file?

I need to make a script, graphical solution as VOM or Veritas Cluster Console are not allow.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if your cluster is on a unix platform, try this command from the shell prompt (preferably as 'root' user, but other's may work as well)

hares -display | grep "your_SG_name_here" > SG_resources

you will find all the information belonging to this service group in the SG_resources file.

if you are a little familiar with commands, grep, awk and sed, it will be a very little work to parse it into DG Volume and mountpoint information.

If you get stuck somewhere, post it here and you will get an answer, I am sure